# Override HTML native drag and drop ghosting effect

Tags: html, css, vuejs3

I have made a a feature using the native HTML drag and drop API in Vue 3. However, I would like to override the opacity that gets added when dragging. I have tried adding to the style like this in my ondragstart event

```
event.currentTarget.style.opacity = 1;
```

but it seems like that style can't be overridden. I have seen a lot of people on various forums complain about how its hard/not possible to change this "ghosting" effect. But if anyone has a solution, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to this problem can be much easier than you think. Adding attribute `!important` to your style will overwrite everything :)

```
event.currentTarget.style.opacity = "1 !important";
```

Let me now if this works :)

Comment: Nope, its still translucent

Answer (score 0):

This done by replacing the default drag behaviour. You setup your own drag experience and then you can control how the browser handles the default behaviour.

Usually, the drag is turned off and a clone is of the node is moved.

Comment: The css in your original post seems to just turn off the ability to drag the item. How would I go about replacing the drag behavior with my own?

Comment: you can see a writeup of how to implement here https://dev.to/dasdaniel/vue3-compisition-api-craeting-a-draggable-element-fo6 and an example here https://jsfiddle.net/dapo/eoq2sm16/